# How to Replicate an array using RavenDB SQL Replication containing values not columns?

Tags: replication, ravendb

I am trying to replicate an array stored in a document in RavenDB as follows:

```
{
  "CreatedAt": "2013-04-03T13:37:12.0261044",
  "IsMostRecent": false,
  "ClientId": "clients/641",
  "ChangeReason": "CommunityBasedAssessmentNewClient",
  "StatusType": "Live",
  "Start": "2013-04-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "End": "2013-04-01T00:00:00.0000000",
  "EndCharge": null,
  "AssessmentDate": null,
  "Correspondence": null,
  "Service": {
    "$type": "Cordia.Care.Core.Models.Personalisation, Cordia.Care.Core",
    "IsDirectBilling": false,
    "Visits": [
     {
        "DayOfWeek": "Monday",
        "Start": "09:00:00",
        "End": "11:00:00",
        "AdditionalResources": false,
        "SocialWork": {
        "Duration": 120,
        "BillableTo": "SocialWork",
        "VisitTasks": [
        "DressingAssistance"
      ]
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      "Duration": 0,
      "BillableTo": "Private",
      "VisitTasks": []
    }
  }
```

The problem I am having is saving     "VisitTasks", I am using the following script for this part but not having any joy:

```
replicateToSocialWork( 
{
        Duration: visit.SocialWork.Duration,
        BillableTo: visit.SocialWork.BillableTo
});

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.SocialWork.VisitTasks.length; i++)
{
    var visitTask = this.Service.Visits.SocialWork.VisitTasks[i];
    replicateToSWVisitTask(
    {
        VisitTask: visitTask
    });
}

replicateToPrivateWork( 
{
        Duration: visit.PrivateWork.Duration,
        BillableTo: visit.PrivateWork.BillableTo
});

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.PrivateWork.VisitTasks.length; i++)
{
    var visitTask = this.Service.Visits.PrivateWork.VisitTasks[i];
    replicateToPWVisitTask(
    {
        VisitTask: visitTask
    });
}
```

This is part of a bigger script that is working, it is just this part I cannot get working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When this executes:

```
 replicateToPWVisitTask(
 {
     VisitTask: visitTask
 });
```

You are trying to replicate the visitTask object serialized to json to the VisitTask.
If you want to send values, you need to extract the values.

Comment: What syntax should I use for this? 

For example:

     replicateToPWVisitTask(
     {
         VisitTask: VisitTask.Value
     });

Not sure how this is done when the array has values like this instead of values like Duration and BillableTo as in my question.

Thanks

Comment: 'for(var x=0; x<visit.SocialWork.VisitTasks.length;x++)
 {
  var visitTask = visit.SocialWork.VisitTasks[x];
  
  replicateToSWVisitTask(
  {
   VisitTask: visitTask
  });
 }'

This is the syntax that I am using just now and struggling to see what I am doing wrong.